# Creating a blood slide on canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm new to canvas and working on creating a simple blood slide, using a transparent rectangle with a gradient circle in the middle that goes from a dark red to a lighter red. The problem I'm having is that while the canvas is the transparent blue I want, I want the blood circle less transparent. How do I keep a transparent background and still have a visible gradient circle on top of it?
This is what my code looks like so far:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="100" 
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(150, 50, 5, 150, 45, 50);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "white");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.globalAlpha = .1;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);

</script>
```

Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Use `grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)");` to have parts of a gradient transparent. The last value in the rgba colour is the alpha value from 0 to 1 inclusive.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. After playing around a little more with using the rgba, I was able to make it a lot better. I also removed the globalAlpha and replaced the normal red and white. This worked really well. @Blindman67